# Sum two awk outputs as single output

Tags: awk

Currently I use the following line to calculate the current Download and Upload speed for my wifi connection which is named wlp4s0:

```
awk '{if(l1){printf ("%.2f", ($2-l1)/1024/1024); print "MB/s"; printf ("%.2f", ($10-l2)/1024/1024); print "MB/s"} else {l1=$2; l2=$10;}}' <(grep wlp4s0 /proc/net/dev) <(sleep 1; grep wlp4s0 /proc/net/dev)
```

The output of this command is for example:

> 1,85MB/s 0,2MB/s

Then I use a second command for calculating Download and Upload BUT for ethernet this time instead of wifi:

```
awk '{if(l1){printf ("%.2f", ($2-l1)/1024/1024); print "MB/s"; printf ("%.2f", ($10-l2)/1024/1024); print "MB/s"} else {l1=$2; l2=$10;}}' <(grep enp3s0 /proc/net/dev) <(sleep 1; grep enp3s0 /proc/net/dev)
```

The output of this command is similar to the first one, for example:

> 1,35MB/s 0,1MB/s

**Question**: How can I combine this two awk statements so that I get only one output with these values added up?
Desired output should be:

> 3,20MB/s 0,3MB/s

So both Download values get added (1,85 + 1,35) and same for Upload (0,2 + 0,1).

It thought it would maybe better to first add the values and add the "MB/s" as the last step. Would this be a better approach?

Comment: are you sure you need both grep & awk ?

Comment: You can do it all in one `awk` call, saving, e.g. `($2-l1)/1024/1024)` as a variable `down` and summing for each file. Then use the `END` rule to output the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this should work, but not tested.

```
$ awk 'function pr(x) {printf "%.2f %s\n", x/1024/1024,"MB/s"}  
       /wlp4s0/ && !w++ {wf2=$2; wf10=$10}
       /enp3s0/ && !e++ {ef2=$2; ef10=$10}                    
       /wlp4s0/ && w==2 {pr($2-wf2); pr($10-wf10); w=0}
       /enp3s0/ && e==2 {pr($2-ef2); pr($10-ef10); e=0}' <(cat /proc/net/dev) <(sleep 1; cat /proc/net/dev)
```

capture the first occurrence of the values and print the scaled difference at the second occurrence.

Perhaps combining two conditions into one if/else would be better...

Comment: Yes this helps me! Last problem: I figured out that wf2 is storing a wrong value. I did this for testing:
`w==1 {wf2=$2; wf10=$10;} w==2 {pr(wf2); pr(wf10); w=0}' <(cat /proc/net/dev) <(sleep 1; cat /proc/net/dev)`
It outputs the value from "lo" interface which is listed above wlp4so in my /proc/net/dev. Do you know how I can fix this? How can I tell that I want to use the value from stored /wlp4s0/?

Comment: try the updated version.  Since you didn't post any input files it's not tested.

Comment: You're right, I should provide an example file next time, sorry. The new version is perfect, I did not know that you can just write "/wlp4s0/" to access the relevant captured values, that is what was missing, thanks for that. So I think the old version should have worked  with that too.

I changed it a little bit though, I sum both Download values and both Upload values now so that I can only two outputs:

Comment: Final solution:

`awk 'function pr(x) {printf "%.2f %s\n", x/1024/1024,"MB/s"}  
       /wlp4s0/ && !w++ {wf2=$2; wf10=$10}
       /enp3s0/ && !e++ {ef2=$2; ef10=$10}                    
       /wlp4s0/ && w==2 {wdown=$2-wf2; wup=$10-wf10; w++}
       /enp3s0/ && e==2 {edown=$2-ef2; eup=$10-ef10; e++}
       w==3 && e==3 {pr(wdown+edown); pr(wup+eup); w=0; e=0}' <(cat /proc/net/dev) <(sleep 1; cat /proc/net/dev)
`

Answer (score 0):

That `sleep` in the process substitution is pretty cute, I don't think I've seen that before.

Here's how I'd approach it (untested):

```
file='/proc/net/dev'
tmp=$(mktemp) &&
cp -- "$file" "$tmp" &&
sleep 1 &&
awk '
    /wlp4s0/ { vals["wifi","dn",NR==FNR] = $2; vals["wifi","up",NR==FNR] = $10 }
    /enp3s0/ { vals["ethr","dn",NR==FNR] = $2; vals["ethr","up",NR==FNR] = $10 }
    END {
        split("wifi ethr", cons)
        split("dn up", dirs)
        for (i=1; i in cons; i++) {
            con = cons[i]
            for (j=1; j in dirs; j++) {
                dir = dirs[j]
                val = (vals[con,dir,0] - vals[con,dir,1])/1024/1024)
                printf "%s %s %.2f MB/s\n", con, dir, val
                tot[dir] += val
            }
        }
        for (j=1; j in dirs; j++) {
            printf "%s %.2f MB/s\n", dir, tot[dir]
        }
    }
' "$tmp" "$file" &&
rm -f "$tmp"
```

Final output formatting left as an exercise :-).

Answer (score 0):

Given the size of `/proc/net/dev` and it being relatively quick to parse, you can write a short script to monitor all the named interfaces and on an VT100 compatible terminal to create a nice little dynamically updating block of information showing the transfer rate for each using ANSI escapes.

The script uses the timeout value of `read` to control the delay between samples (press `'q'` to quit):

```
#!/bin/bash

dev="/proc/net/dev"
ifaces=($(awk '/[a-z0-9]+:/{print $1}' "$dev"))
bytes=($(awk '/[a-z0-9]+:/{print $2}' "$dev"))
nfaces=${#ifaces[@]}
c=0

tput civis
printf "Device   Bytes/sec\n--------------------\n"

while [ "$c" != 'q' ]; do
    read -n 1 -t 1 -r c
    if [ $? -ge 128 ]; then
        current=($(awk '/[a-z0-9]+:/{print $2}' "$dev"))
        for ((i = 0; i < nfaces; i++)); do
            rate=$((${current[i]}-${bytes[i]}))
            printf "%-8s %s\033[K\n" "${ifaces[i]}" "$rate"
        done
        printf "\033[${nfaces}A"
        bytes=(${current[@]})
    fi
done

printf "\033[1D%c\r\033[${nfaces}B" "${ifaces[0]:0:1}"
tput cnorm

exit 0
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash readnet.sh
Device   Bytes/sec
--------------------
eth0:    0
lo:      0
wlan0:   624
```

Just another way to skin the proverbial cat.